# yum libc-client-devel repository missing

Tags: php, centos, libc

In some Centos system, the *libc-client* and *libc-client-devel* packages can not be found (IIRC that is in the official repository).

So when building PHP imap extension, the operation failed.

How to find the repository?

Comment: Whatever an official repository is, you have to tell, they normally have a name and an address. Similar like CentOS that has a version, same as PHP and not to forget the extension you're building. All such specifics are missing, as well as you don't show how you configure and run the build of that PHP extension, nor you didn't share how you normally practice searching for packages on your operating system. And given only _some Centos systems_, how does it work on the other ones? You have not shared either.